# Skip marshalling field in Go

Tags: json, go, marshalling

Hi how would I skip marshalling the Data property in this example?

Once I receive this response, I have to parse this data property as JSON in my frontend because it has been remarshalled. I would like everything to be ready to use from the Go backend. I'm not sure how to do this. Or perhaps I can update the main unmarshaled response with the unmarshaled Data so I don't get this issue; not sure how to do this.

1. Get response from API and unmarshal it
2. Get another API response based on "Data"
3. Unmarshal "Data" and update it
4. Marshal updated "Data" and update original response
5. Final marshal to send to client

Generic Example:

```golang
res, err := ... // from API 

type Response struct {
  Id string
  Data string
}

var response Response

json.Unmarshal([]byte(res), &response)

res, err = ... // fetch additional data based on response 

var data map[string]interface{} // Data may have unknown properties

json.Unmarshal([]byte(res), &data)

data["knownproperty"] = "changed"

json, _ := json.Marshal(data)
data := string(json)

// update original response
response.Data = data

// marshal to send to client
json, _ = json.Marshal(response)
data = string(json)

fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", data)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can embed `Response` in a struct with its own `Data` field of type `json.RawMessage`: https://go.dev/play/p/NJbtxdJetMY

Comment: Thanks for that - my only issue is I'm not sure how to cleanly merge the original data (with potentially unknown properties so I can't statically form this) and the updated knownproperty with `Data:     updated_data,`. That will just replace the entire Data property with "knownproperty":"changed". I am trying to convert my `data map[string]interface{}` into a byte array to do this, not sure if this is the right approach though.

Comment: Think I found a solution - convert the updated marshalled data into a byte array and then pass that into the rawMessage field. Thanks for the help, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide an example JSON response from the first API call, and an example JSON response from the second API call. And then also provide the desired JSON output that is the result of combining the two JSON API responses. There may be a better, more idiomatic approach to the problem than what you have currently.

Comment: Sure. The first API call returns this `{ "total": 50, "page": 1, "data":  [ { "type": "image", "link": "https://link.com/data.json" } ]}`. The second API call comes from fetching the JSON which returns { name: "1st video", link: "https://example.com/myvideo.mp4" }. So I update the type based on the link type (using content-type) so final output looks like: `{ "total": 50, "page": 1, "data":  [ { "type": "video", "link": "https://link.com/data.json" } ]}`.

Comment: Alex here's an example of how I would approach it: https://go.dev/play/p/6WLgGoN1YtZ. If the structure of the individual data items isn't static then, depending on whether the number of variations is limited or not, instead of `DataItem` and `DataItemInfo` I would either use a custom unmarshaler or a map of strings or interfaces.

Comment: Hi mkopriva, I'm trying to implement this with a dynamic response (at line 37 in your demo). Since I have to use `map[string]interface{}` as in the original post to cover all bases (I think). Your solution would be perfect if the second response data was always consistent (this data comes from users who may add their own custom properties, this could be 1 or many).

Comment: You can do that, that's fine. It's just that the code that needs to figure out the type of the image will be a bit more complex, it will have to probably range over the map and do some type assertions.